# Add/remove textbox value when checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, textbox

I have the following jquery code where i want to remove the value from the textfield if the checkbox is unchecked and add if it is checked.

initially all the values comes in the textbox as the `^` seperator. and all checkboxes checked

here is y piece of code:

```
$(document).on('change','._invoice',function() { 
    var mystr = $(this).attr('data-id').is(":checked");
    if(mystr) {
        var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
        $(this).attr("checked", returnVal);
    }    
    });
});
```

Text field values and i also want to remove the separator and add the name at the last with `^` as separator.

```
Robert Berenson^Nancy Foster^Richard Gourhan^LORI HEDMAN^Pui Hoang^Linda Lee^Kristen McDonald^Matthew Miller^Tricia Roland^Terry West
```

Comment: `$(this).is(":checked").attr('data-id');` try this one

Comment: `.attr('data-id').is(":checked")` That's your problem. `attr()` returns a string, so calling `.is()` on that will fail.

Comment: but how do i remove the data and add again on uncheck and check again using the seperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is that change text of textbox on checkbox change event. Then means you need to get text of every checked checkbox and set it to textbox, when any checkbox is changed.

```js
$(".check").change(function(){
    var text = "";
    $(".check:checked").each(function(){ 
        text += text != "" ? "^" : "";
        if ($(this).prop("checked"))
            text += $(this).val();
    });
    $(".text").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="Text5" />
<br/>
<input type="text" class="text" />
```

Comment: cool, but what if the name is in middle and both sides, i have ^ seperator, sorry i missed that wording while u were aswering this

Comment: @Daniel What is meaning of `name is in middle and both sides`? I can't understand

Comment: means like this: ^Robert baratheon^

Comment: @Daniel Is it your purpose?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a Lot, I managed to get t working by your help, Great Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = document.getElementById( 'droptxt' ),
            content = document.getElementById( 'content' ),
            list = document.querySelectorAll( '.content input[type="checkbox"]' ),
            quantity = document.querySelectorAll( '.quantity' );
        txt.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            content.classList.toggle( 'show' )
        } )

        window.onclick = function( e ) {
            if ( !e.target.matches( '.list' ) ) {
                if ( content.classList.contains( 'show' ) ) content.classList.remove( 'show' )
            }
        }

        list.forEach( function( item, index ) {
            item.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                calc()
            } )
        } )

        function calc() {
            for ( var i = 0, arr = []; i < list.length; i++ ) {
            let spanArray = [];
            document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(element => {
                spanArray.push(element.innerHTML);
            });
            
                if ( list[ i ].checked ) arr.push( list[ i ].value + " "+ spanArray)
            }   
            txt.value = arr.join(', ')
        }
```

```css
h1 {
            color: #0000ff;
        }
        #droptxt {
            padding: 8px;
            width: 300px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block
        }
        .content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            min-width: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            z-index: 1
        }
        .content div {
            padding: 10px 15px
        }
        .content div:hover {
            background-color: #ddd
        }
        .show {
            display: block
        }
```

```html
<h1>KIAAT</h1>
    <b>Adding/Removing Checkbox Values into TextArea</b>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="droptxt" class="list" placeholder="Select the values" readonly>
        <div id="content" class="content">
            <div id="market" class="list">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="market" class="list" value="apple" /> Apple</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="list">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="banana" class="list" value="Banana" /> Banana</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="list">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="pineapple" class="list" value="Pineapple" /> Pineapple</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```